# How do I link to an Access Database using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

```
            <div class="main-container">

                    Username:<br>
                    <input type="text" name="uname" value="Username">
                    <br>
                    Password:<br>
                    <input type="password" name="pword" value="Password">
                    <br><br>
                    <input type="submit" value="AddRecord">
                    <input type="reset" value="Cancel">
            </div>
        </div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
function AddRecord() {
var adoConn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
var adoRS = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");

adoConn.Open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = C:\\Documents\\Writings.mdb");

adoRS.Open("Select * From User", adoConn, 1, 3);
        if(!rs.bof){
        rs.MoveFirst();
            while(!rs.eof){
                var data=rs(1);
                if(data==user.value){
                alert("This user already exists!");
                exists=1;
                }else{
                break;
                rs.movenext();
                }
            }
        }

if(exists!=1){


adoRS.AddNew;
adoRS.Fields("UserName")=user.value;
adoRS.Update;

adoRS.Close();
adoConn.Close();  

alert("User successfully registered!");
document.cookie=user.value;

window.location="https://www.google.co.uk";
}
</script>
```

This doesn't work the button does nothing. I've tried moving my database but that also doesn't work. I currently work using Google Chrome. My database is called Writings and is the folder documents.
The website is supposed to get the information inputted from the text boxes and put it in the table but fro some reason it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating a webpage, you usually want people to browse it and then fill and submit. In the code you showed, the database is local so if 100 people want to submit, each has the own database or all need to use same computer.
For this kind of job you need to use a web service that is working with a central database and then, you can use javascript to call that service to insert data into database. For example you can use c# with MS Sql server or even Access database or use php with mysql.

Comment: What could I use instead of ActiveX?

Comment: You should write a web service and then service must be connected to DB

Answer (score 0):

You are using `ActiveX` to connect to the Access Database. This won't work in chrome, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37994633/1641867) indicates:

> To create a COM object (which is what ActiveXObject did), you'd need to use a browser with native support for ActiveX (old IE) or a browser you could use and/or write an old-style (NPAPI) "plugin" on.
>
> All major browsers have discontinued or are actively (no pun) discontinuing support for the NPAPI plugin mechanism because of the security issues around it.

So you'll have to use an old Internet Explorer with ActiveX enabled for your script.

**This is old technology and shouldn't be used anymore. Move your database to a central server.**

Comment: What could I use instead of ActiveX?

Comment: So, the easy way would be to import your access database into a sql server instance and build some kind backend with a language / platform of your choice. If you want to keep your database on the clients, you could try to [convert the access file to sqlite](https://github.com/arturasn/mdb2sqlite) and access it with [sql.js](https://github.com/kripken/sql.js). But I'm not an expert in this topic - this is just an idea. Please do a little research on your own...